# alternative of mysql query date interval

Tags: mysql, sql

What is alternative of this statement?

```
between date_sub(curdate(), Interval 12 month) and date_sub(curdate(),Interval 1 day)
```

Comment: `date_add(curdate(), interval -12 month)` ???

Comment: no this one is not working

Answer (score 0):

Some what like this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourtable 
WHERE (`start` >= :start) 
AND (`end` <= :end) 
OR (`start` <= :end) 
AND (`end` >= :start);
```

Comment: how can i calculate for one year automatically. this query take manually date.